# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient

Tags: java, scrapy, htmlunit

He intentado de todo pero no obtengo resultados, estoy usando una API llamada HtmlUnit para sacar información de una pagina web sin embargo al momento de crear el WebClient, me salta el error en detalle, he intentado de muchas maneras pero no logro resolver el error por favor espero puedan ayudarme.

```java
     public static void SunatTipoCambio () throws  Exception{


        try {

            try( WebClient ClienteWeb    = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)){            
            HtmlPage pagina = ClienteWeb.getPage("http://www.sunat.gob.pe/cl-at-ittipcam/tcS01Alias");
            ClienteWeb.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            ClienteWeb.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            ClienteWeb.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

            String contenido = pagina.asText();

            ClienteWeb.close();
            System.out.println("ENTRANDO A SUNAT ");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR SunatTipoCambio : "+e.getMessage());
        }
```

aqui invoco el metodo desde el servlet

```java
private void listaClientes (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException {

          String json = ClientesDAO.ClientesLista().toString();
          Gson gg = new Gson();
          System.out.println("Servlet Factura listaClientes : "+ gg.toJson(json));  

          // aqui lo invoco 
          try {
            FacturaDAO.SunatTipoCambio();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

          response.setContentType("application/json");
          response.getWriter().write(gg.toJson(json)); 

    }
```

incluso declaro solo la variable dentro del servlet, solo para por probar y sigo obteniendo el mismo error

```java
private void listaClientes (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException {

          String json = ClientesDAO.ClientesLista().toString();
          Gson gg = new Gson();
          System.out.println("Servlet Factura listaClientes : "+ gg.toJson(json));  

          // i create the webclient just for try 

          WebClient cliente = new WebClient();

          response.setContentType("application/json");
          response.getWriter().write(gg.toJson(json)); 

    }
```

el error es

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
>     at Servlet.ServletFactura.listaClientes(ServletFactura.java:79)     at
>   Servlet.ServletFactura.doPost(ServletFactura.java:55)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)

Estoy seguro que las librerías estan importadas correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es Stack Overflow en **español** por favor traduce tu pregunta al idioma del sitio.

Comment: Listo modificación realizada, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que tienes importadas las librerías pero solo para compilar, debes asegurarte que todas las librerías estén en el `Deployment Assembly`, porque al desplegar en el servidor si no están listadas aquí eclipse asume que las librerías son solo para compilar pero no para ser agregadas al WAR porque serán proporcionadas por el servidor o en tiempo de ejecución.

Este problema es común que funcione local y al correr en el servidor falle por falta de un o varias librería.

Verifica que seguiste estos pasos al agregar las librerías externas:

1. Clic Derecho en el proyecto -> properties. y se abrirá la ventana de
   propiedades.
2. Selecciona "Deployment Assembly" en el panel izquierdo.
3. Clic "add"
4. Selecciona "Java Build Path Entries".
5. Selecciona ADD he importa todas las librerías requeridas, 
       si ya están en el proyecto pero no están listadas aquí selecciona ADD 
       -> java build path entries y selecciona todas las librerías.

Y para confirmar sin necesidad de desplegar:

- Clic Derecho en el proyecto -> export -> `.war` file.
  Y si realizaste correctamente el proceso encontraras todas las librerías en `/WEB-INF/lib` dentro del war generado.

Comment: Roberto, usted es un genio, me funciono tal cual me indicaste, me has ayudado muchisimo amigo, funciona ahora si genial, muchisimas gracas , te mando un enorme saludo y espero que en futuras oportunidades puedas asesorarme, muchas gracias

Comment: Es bueno saber que lograste solucionar el problema, por eso existe esta comunidad y seguramente si no soy yo otros sabrán darte una solución.