# Eclipse me da el mensaje: Classpath entry X will not be exported or published

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy trabajando con Servlets, JSP's y MySQL con MVC en la perspectiva Java EE en ECLIPSE y al momento de agregar el JAR del conector MySQL a mi proyecto en eclipse me aparece que no puede cargarlo, en la imagen se puede apreciar como si esta agregado en el BuildPath del proyecto.

Debo mencionar que la clase que se conecta a la BD funciona con el mismo Driver pero en la perspectiva de Java SE....   Alguna sugerencia o solución??

Comment: Lo que sucede es que tienes importada una librería que te funcionara cuando ejecutes en eclipse pero no cuando despliegues o empaquetes tu war, si quieres que la librería este en el compilado .war solo sigue los pasos de esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-gargoylesoftware-htmlunit-webclient/298410#298410  y si te funciona marcala como solución, un saludo.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, en efecto se tienen que agregar las Jar WEB-INF/lib/"jars".....

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, lo que ves no es un error, es un warning.

En terminos generales, quiere decir que deberás de proveer tu aplicación junto con la librería para conectarse a MySQL, es decir tu `mysql-conector-java0.0.18.jar`.

### ¿Qué pasa si estás desplegando en un servidor empresarial (jar<sup>1</sup>, ear, war<sup>1</sup>, o carpeta explotada)?

Deberás asegurarte que tu servidor tenga la librería para el driver de la base de datos preferentemente en la misma versión para evitar cualquier posible error. Para ello normalmente hay dos formas, o agregarlo a una carpeta en particular (esto lo he probado en [glassfish](/questions/tagged/glassfish)), o usar su acceso de administrador al dashboard y hacerlo mediant formularios web (esto lo he hecho tanto en servidores glassfish como servidores [jboss](/questions/tagged/jboss)).

### ¿Qué pasa si yo despliego mi propio servidor embebido<sup>2</sup>?

Si por ejemplo usas [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) y estás lanzando tu aplicación con su servidor embebido (generalmente [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat), o una versión modificada como [payara](/questions/tagged/payara)), implica que deberás de agregar tu librería al classpath al momento de correr, por ejemplo mediante

```
java -jar miaplicacion.jar -cp mysql-conector-java0.0.18.jar
```

### Todo eso suena muy complicado, ¿Qué alternativas tengo?

Bueno, además de los plugins para empaquetar y desplegar que a veces existen en los ides, yo personalmente te recomiendo usar algún sistema de construcción ( por razones de complejidad y porque ya está medio ruco excluiremos al dese [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) ), como por ejemplo:

- [maven](/questions/tagged/maven)
- [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle)
- [leiningen](/questions/tagged/leiningen) (Esa madre solamente he visto que la usen los compis que programan en [clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure))
- [ivy](/questions/tagged/ivy)
- [bazel](/questions/tagged/bazel) <sup>3</sup>
- [sbt](/questions/tagged/sbt)
- [grape](/questions/tagged/grape)
- [buildr](/questions/tagged/buildr)

Muchos de estos sistemas de construcción te permiten empaquetar tu aplicación (y algunos incluso desplegar en servidor empresarial o ejecutar desde consola para que no te canses escribiendo) en lo que se llama coloquialmente *fat-jar* (a veces se usa incluso el término *fat-war*, o *fat-ear*, pero con el primer término te das a entender con los gringos), es decir, un archivo de despliegue con todas las dependencias necesarias dentro, y estas generalmente tienen precedencia sobre las que tenga ya instalado el servidor empresarial si es el primer caso.

### Notas

<sup>1</sup> Creo que solamente aplica si usas spring, si quieres tomar ventaja de un servidor JEE o estás haciendo Enterprise Java Beans no

<sup>2</sup> Implica que tienes un main y despliegas como un jar por lo general

<sup>3</sup> Este es bastante complejo de usar, pero viene de Google, así que es bastante bueno